# IPhone simulator vs. Device issue (open GL)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ios-simulator

I am developing an iPhone application using openGl ES 2.0, and after a lot of testing in the simulator I installed the application on my iPhone(3GS) to see how well it preformed. When the app launched it started up fine with no errors, but nothing showed up, however the background was the appropriate color.

Does anybody have any ideas/pointers about what might be causing this issue? If code/details would help just let me know what section of code you would like to see.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple app that just displays a cube (for example) and seeing if that exhibits the same problem? If it doesn't add a little bit of your code and test again. Repeat until it fails.

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that but it's looking like thats the only option because I have no idea what could be causing this sort of an issue.

Comment: You can't post your entire application code here so you'd have to reduce the problem to the minimum repeatable case anyway. In doing this you might well find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Check the constraints on various functions you may use. For example, by default the width and height for `glTexImage2D` must each be powers of 2 (or powers of 2 plus 2, if you are using a border). There is an extension that allows for non-power-of-two textures, but in my experience this extension is not present or is not completely implemented on at least some devices (i.e. it works for GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE but not GL_REPEAT).

Comment: You should read the GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot and GL_OES_texture_npot extension specifications, they explain the limitation you're seeing with NPOT textures. It's not a implementation problem, is meant to be that way.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: Ah, ok. OpenGL ES 2.0 already allows NPOT textures with GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, no extension required.

Answer (score 0):

The Device is strict about case-sensitivity in filenames -- check to make sure that if you are loading Shaders, that the filenames referenced in your code are identical to their actual filesystem names.

Also, if you are in xCode 4, go to your Target Build Phases settings and make sure all of the shaders you use are in Copy Bundle Resources.

Finally, if the shaders appear in 'Compile Sources', you should remove them from there. You'll need to Clean your project and then re-build.